# Insert into wordpress database - Call to a member function insert()

Tags: php, database, wordpress, sql-insert

Im having an issue with inserting data into the wordpress database through my plugin.
My plugin uses a shortcode to display a form from which some calculations are made and then that information is the then supposed to be inserted into the database but I end up getting this message.

I can't seem to get it to work?.. Any help would be appreciated greatly.

**PLUGIN CODE used for the insert:**

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-config.php' );
$wpdb->insert(
    'wp_wine_bookings',
    array(
        'name' => $_POST['name'], 
        'last_name' => $_POST['lname'],
        'phone_number' => $_POST['phone_num'], 
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
        'booking_status' => "Booked",
        'tour_name' => $_POST['tourname'],
        'tour_date' => $_POST['tourdates'],
        'number_of_people' =>  $_POST['num_ppl'],
        'price' => $_POST['priceget'],
        'state' => $_POST['state'],
        'city' => $_POST['city'],
        'country' => $_POST['country'],
        'mobile' => $_POST['mobile'],
        'preffered_pickup_point' => $_POST['locationpickup'],
        'arrival_date' => $_POST['arrivaldate'],
        'name_on_credit_card' => $_POST['cn'],
        'credit_card_type' => $_POST['type'],
        'payment_date' => date("d-m-y"),
        'occasion' => $_POST['occasion'],
        'requirementsO' => $_POST['requirementsO'],
        'requirementsP' => $_POST['requirementsP']
    ), 
    array( 
        '%s', 
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s'
    ) 
);
```

**PHP ERROR:**

> Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in
>   /home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/BookingWT/booknow.php
>   on line 52

Comment: Your error is self explanatory: the function insert() does not exist on the object $wpdb. Where is $wpdb being set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First:**
Why you have included the file `wp-config.php`? you don't need to include this at all.

**Second:**

You're accessing the instance of `wpdb` class (`$wpdb`). Which is in local scope.

You have to make `$wpdb` [`global`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php):

```
global $wpdb;        // <--- making $wpdb as global
$wpdb->insert(
...
...
```